# Automatically changing a posts status to draft based on magic fields

Tags: custom-field

I would like to set a post to Draft automatically based on a custom field date.

Note: **[I am using the plugin Magic Fields.](http://magicfields.org/)**

Based on the following code I want to use a custom field 'expiration' to give the date.

```
function sfn_show_expire() { 
    global $wpdb; 
    $server_time = date('mdy'); 
    $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'show' AND post_status = 'publish'"); 
    if( !empty($result)) {
        foreach ($result as $a) { 
            $show_time = get_the_time('mdy', $a->ID ); 
            if ( $server_time > $show_time) { 
                $my_post = array(); 
                $my_post['ID'] = $a->ID; 
                    $my_post['post_status'] = 'draft'; 
                wp_update_post( $my_post ); 
            } 
        } // end foreach 
    }
} 
add_action( 'init', 'sfn_show_expire' );
```

Ultimately I would like to make this in a cron job, but for now any suggestions to the code would be great.

Comment: Related questions: [Set Expiration Date of a Post from the Frontend with wp_insert_post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6631/set-expiration-date-of-a-post-from-the-frontend-with-wp-insert-post), [Posts wont expire…](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10793/posts-wont-expire)

Comment: I tried changing `$show_time = get_the_time('mdy', $a->ID );  ` to `$show_time = get_post_meta('expiration', 'mdy', $a->ID );` but that did not work.

Comment: questions about 3rd party plugins such as magic fields are offtopic here and not in this stacks scope

Answer (score 1):

For cron jobs, take a look at the [Transients API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API).

The rest could maybe be acchieved with something *like* the following. I have never ever used the transient API before and code's not tested.

```
function set_post_to_draft()
{
    global $post;

    if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'set_to_draft_key' ) == true );
        return $post->post_status == 'draft';
}
set_transient( 'post_to_draft_transient', set_post_to_draft(), 60*60*12 ); // 12h interval
```

Comment: How do I then compare the date given in the custom field to the current date to see if the post should be turned into draft?

Comment: I guess the transient API (works close to Options API) does checks the timespan (3rd Arg.) and saves it to the DB. Then compares on every request the curr. timestamp against the 60*60*12 and the save to the DB.

Comment: The problem appears to be that I am using Magic Fields which basically uses get instead of get_post_meta.  I am not sure how to use get within the functions php.

Comment: Are "magic fields" part of a plugin?

Comment: Yes the plugin is called Magic Fields.

Comment: Edited the Question above to state the plugin I am using.  My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Ah, a fork of flutter... switch to http://podscms.org

Comment: I will take a look at Podscms, but I would really like to solve this with Magic Fields.

Comment: After doing some projects with pods, i strongly recommend switching. pods is the **only** real cms plugin and it gives you stand alone tables that connect in an extremly smart way and a easy to use class to handle all db related stuff. you also got public forms and else and 2.0 is up and coming. imo a) the better choice and b) something where i could help. i really don't know magic fields (and flutter was no good plugin).

Answer (score 0):

I used a plugin called [WP Crontrol](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/)

Then in my `functions.php` file I added the following code:

```
function draft_past_events() {

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'events', // <-- Enter Post Type
        'post_status'=> 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'=> -1
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);

    while($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post();

        $event_id = get_the_ID();
        $event_end_date = get_field('event_end_date'); // <-- Replace with your custom field
        $today = date('Y-m-d');

        if ($event_end_date < $today) {
            wp_update_post(array(
                'ID' =>  get_the_ID(),
                'post_status' => 'draft'
            ));
        }

    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();

}

add_action('draft_past_events_hook', 'draft_past_events');
```

Essentially what this does is set any published post to draft if the custom field date is less than today's date. Ensure you use 'Y-m-d' for date format for this to work.

Within the plugin, you can now create a new Cron event.

In my example, I ran it every day at 1:00am using a standard cron event. The hook name used in my example is; `draft_past_events_hook`

Answer (score -3):

few ways to do this task. Here i used to follow this code.

```
$update_post = array(
            'ID'            => $id,
            'post_status'   =>  'private',
            'post_type' =>  'job' );
            wp_update_post($update_post);
```

Comment: Please add the relevant information to your answer, instead of just linking to it - thanks.

Comment: you can use a link to support an answer but your answer needs to make sense and be usable even if all the links are broken. I've edited out the link to your article, but this doesn't answer the question and has nothing to do with custom fields

Comment: @TomJNowell this is spam. I'm amazed you don't delete spam on this site.